# How to insert data without knowing no off columns in php

Tags: php

I have a variable number of fields in a table,where the number of column headings are directly fetched from database,so the number of heading increases as the data from database increase(eg-demo,demo1,demo2,..).For each column there is a selectbox,here i have given name for check box as `txtcheck".$i."[]` where `$i` is set as an incriminating value.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='txtcheck".$i."[]'  value='1'>
```

My doubt is how can i fetch the checkbox post value when form submission.I dont know whether this is correct way nor find a way to efficiently do this. Please advise.

[image: this is the view of my html table]

Comment: Could you please share your full code along with PHP tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` of your checkboxes shouldn't be incremented, but only be `txtcheck[]`. In this case the selected boxes will be transfered as array.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='txtcheck[]' value='1' />
```

In your PHP code you can access this array with `$_POST['txtcheck']`.

```
<?php
    $checkedBoxes = $_POST['txtcheck'];
    foreach ($checkedBoxes as $checkdBox) {
        // Here you can handle each box that was checked in your form, e.g. echo it's value
        echo $checkedBox . ' ';
    }
?>
```

So if you checked e.g. boxes with values `1`, `5` and `10` your output will be `1 5 10`

Comment: Thank you for the detail,but how can i fetch data from each checkbox

Comment: `print_r($_POST['txtcheck'])` by using this @vyshaghs

Comment: Please see my improved example above @vyshaghs